# Measuring volume with eTape Liquid Level Sensor + Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have the [12in Tape Sensor](http://www.milonetech.com/Purchase_eTape.html) and an Arduino Uno. I'd like to get use this to measure volume in a cup. They gave me a resistor and a little connector for the 4 pins with the sensor, and I have some wire and a Multimeter.

I am really unsure of how to do even this very basic thing. I would like to extend this into a more useful hack, but right now I'm trying to get basic functionality. In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7TCZ3nOfGo), it looks like they're literally just connecting two ends to the multimeter and that works. I have 4 pins though.

Where do I begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to create the "Simple Voltage Divider" circuit found in [the datasheet](http://www.milonetech.com/uploads/eTape_Datasheet_12110215TC-12_040213.pdf) and connect that to an analog input. Apply power to pin 1, ground to pin 2, and connect pins 3 and 4 together to the input. You can then perform a normal ADC conversion and then from there determine the height of the liquid.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqqsMF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So I don't need to use the resistor to simply get something to print out values from a pin on my Arduino? Should I use Vin, 5V, or 3.3V for the power (first pin). Can I use, say, pin 13 for my input?

Comment: @MarkLyons: The strip already comes with a matched resistor (Rref) that you should use in order to compensate for the temperature of the liquid. V+ should be the same voltage as the power supplied to the Arduino, at least until you start getting into low-level MCU details. You need to connect it to one of the analog inputs ("A*n*").